# F# incorrect type and another incorrect type in the function call

Tags: f#

Not sure what's off about this code. I want to use this as the main function to print a string or return not enough arguments. What's incorrect about this VS15 isn't very helpful in this instance.

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    if (List.length argv) >= 1 then
        printfn "Hello %s" argv.[0]; 0
    else
        printfn "Not enough arguments"; 1

main ["Test"]
```

Comment: The parameter type for `EntryPoint` in .NET is `array`. (On mobile, will write answer / delete when @workstation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though you didn't specify what error you get and where it appears (please always do that when asking questions), I can see what's wrong with your code: you're treating `argv` as if it was a `List`, but a .NET program entry point must accept an argument of type `Array` - specifically, array of strings - `string[]`.

If you switch out `List.length` for `Array.length`, the function will compile.

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  if (Array.length argv) >= 1 then
      printfn "Hello %s" argv.[0]; 0
  else
      printfn "Not enough arguments"; 1
```

Now, if you want to call this function, you would want to supply an argument that is an array, not `List`. In F#, the brackets are used to denote a list. If you want to denote an array, you need to use bracket-pipes instead:

```
main [| "Test |]
```

---

**EDIT in response to comment:**

> Normally you wouldn't need to "call" the entry point function explicitly. Entry point is the "start" of the program, there are no other functions calling it. This is why the entry point function must be the last function in the last file of the program. If you do place any code after the entry point, the compiler will give you an error.
>   The way you wrote the call `main ["Test"]`, I assumed you just wanted to execute this call in F# interactive, which is a popular way of verifying your code without building and running it. Once you are ready to compile, you should remove this call.

---

Finally, I'd like to point out that you're actually accessing the array twice: first to check its length, then to fetch its first item. You can do both in one step using pattern matching:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  match argv with
  | [|name|] -> printfn "Hello %s" name; 0
  | _ -> printfn "Not enough or too many arguments"; 1
```

And look: this way, the program actually became slightly more valid. If you look closer, you'll notice that your original program accepts any number of arguments, but only actually uses the first one. This is a bit "unclean", so to say. The above version using pattern matching does one better: it will take exactly as many arguments as is needed for its function, or print an error message otherwise.

Comment: Normally you wouldn't place it anywhere. The program entry point is called "from outside the program", so to speak. No other function in the program should call the entry point. That's what "entry point" means. It's the point of entry into the program. I assumed you only wrote this call in order to execute it in F# interactive, which is a popular way of verifying your code without building and running it.

Comment: I am not doing anything. It is you who is trying to do something and having problems. I am trying to address those problems to the extent I see them in your code. Perhaps you should try to rephrase your question to describe more precisely what it is you're trying to do, what is not working, what errors you get, where they are, etc.

Comment: In order to execute the entry point, you need to compile the program to obtain the `.exe` file, then go to command line and run that program, like `program.exe World`.

Comment: Also, this last comment makes me think that not only are you very new to F#, but you're also very new to programming in general. If that's the case, I would recommend that you first try to read some books, then go through some tutorials, and only then try your own experiments.

Comment: This is getting a bit out of hand. If you don't even know what a command line is, you definitely need some fundamental computer knowledge before attempting to write programs.